# Partial dependency management in python

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, pipenv, python-poetry

I am managing a rather big python project, with lots of dependencies, that is intended to be run within the [TensorFlow docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/). A common way of defining which dependencies are to be installed in production, is though a lock file generated by a tool like [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/) or [Poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/). When creating such a lock file you usually specify *all* python dependencies in order to ensure no conflicts between packages. But since the TensorFlow docker container comes preinstalled with TensorFlow and all of its dependencies, I would really like to have those packages excluded from my lock file to avoid double installs. I still, however, want my dependency management tool to account for the presence of a certain version of TensorFlow when resolving dependencies for the lock file.

Is there a way to generate lock files that account for preinstalled packages in the environment without having them included in the lock file?

Comment: Why do you think there will be double installs? If you're installing from a requirements file with `pip -r` and some of the dependencies are already satisfied, it won't install them again. If you want to accept a version range instead of a specific version, [that's possible](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files). This assuming you're not installing to a virtualenv, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're installing your packages into the TensorFlow Docker image, then the TensorFlow dependency is already "locked" by the image name and tag, e.g. `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0`. So specify your *other* Python dependencies in your `Pipfile`.

For example, your `Dockerfile` could contain:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0-py3

RUN pip3 install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /yourproject
WORKDIR /yourproject

RUN pipenv --three --site-packages
RUN pipenv install
```

Then you have TensorFlow and all your other dependencies:

```
$ docker build . -t yourproject && docker run -it yourproject bash
# build info not shown
root@b04fc204d239:/yourproject# pipenv run python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"
Loading .env environment variables…
2.0.0
```